# What is the significance of the flashing lights?

Tags: independence-day

In ID4 (Independence Day), there are 3 helicopters sent up to greet the alien craft. One of the copters is fitted with a set of light panels that flash the lights in a specific pattern/sequence. What is the significance of this? Is this something made up for the movie or is the light pattern/sequence meaningful in real life?

I'm looking for an answer on why would they choose to do such a thing and not expect to be received as hostile.

Comment: Two different questions here. "What is the significance of this" It's an attempt to communicate with the aliens, and a homage to Close Encounters of the Third Kind.  "Is the light pattern/sequence meaningful in real life?" - good question! Some googling done, but nothing I can quote yet, but looks like made up for movie.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that it was a reference to the movie Close Encounters of the Third Kind. In that film (the scene is on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4PYI6TzqYk)) humans use a board with flashing lights (similar to the lights on the helicopters) and music to communicate with Aliens.

Comment: I never imagined it to be a *Close Encounters* reference.  I always imagined it was supposed to be the very same unknown government agency in charge of greeting aliens as depicted in *Close Encounters*.

Answer (score 2):

### In-universe explanation

This is explained in the film's [official novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0061056871), co-authored by Dean Devlin, ID4's producer.

The flashing lights were supposed to be an attempt to communicate with the aliens and to demonstrate our desire for peaceful co-existence:

> The president picked up a remote control and switched on the
> television. The Apache had just reached the front of the huge
> spaceship and turned on its light boards. The powerful lights began to
> flash on and off, creating a repeating sequential pattern. **The staff
> at SETI, alter several hours of furious on-line discussion and a
> blizzard of foxes, had come up with a simple mathematical progression,
> a message written in what they hoped would be a universally
> comprehensible language.**
>
> **The entire sequence would repeat every three
> minutes, followed by a display of the word “peace”’ written in ten
> different earthly languages.** It wasn’t much, but it was a beginning.

### Out-of-universe explanation

Echoing djmadscribbler's answer, the effect was presumably a riff off the lightboard depicted in Close Encounters, a film that Dean Devlin described, in [this interview](http://movietalk-britannia.blogspot.co.uk/2006/12/e-mail-interview-with-dean-devlin.html) as being one of his favourites:

> **Devlin:** *I don't know what the future holds. My passions have been for mainstream, popcorn movies. That's what I usually go to see on a
> Friday night. **I fell in love with the movies by watching Star Wars,
> or Jaws, or Close Encounters of the Third Kind.** One day, I hope to
> make a film as great as those.*